# Java: What does <T extends Parcelable> T mean for return type?

Tags: java

I came across this syntax:

```
 public <T extends Parcelable> T getParcelable(String key)
```

What does it mean to have  before the return type?

What about a question mark instead of T?

```
SparseArray<? extends Parcelable> array =(SparseArray<? extends Parcelable>) obj;
```

Comment: Read about [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: @Reimeus I tried my best to elucidate it. Have a look at my answer. I am a nooblet when it comes to generics :D

Answer (score 2):

```
public <T extends Parcelable>
```

It means that the value returned will be an instance of **any** class which descends from `Parcelable` or implements the `Parcelable` interface.

```
SparseArray<? extends Parcelable> array
```

It means that the `array` will hold objects of any class as long as they descend from `Parcelable` or implement the `Parcelable` interface.

Have a look at [Understanding upper and lower bounds on ? in Java Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795709/understanding-upper-and-lower-bounds-on-in-java-generics)