# Returning a generic List with an upper bound

Tags: java, generics

My question is an extension of this post.

If I have a method like this:

```
public static <E extends CharSequence, T extends E> List<T> doIt(List<E> nums) {
return null;
}
```

Why this code compiles ? Why super String is compatible with T extends CharSequence

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<CharSequence> in = new ArrayList<>();

    List<? super String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    result = doIt(in);        
}
```

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795709/understanding-upper-and-lower-bounds-on-in-java-generics?rq=1?

Comment: I would simply the code removing the initialization of ```result```, is not adding anything to the problem and that value is overwritten immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The code works because `<? super String>` and `<? extends CharSequence>` are not mutually exclusive bounds; `String` and `CharSequence` comply with both.

Notice that it works even if there is some classes that comply with one constraint but not with the other (for example `Object` of `String` but it does not extends `CharSequence`), so long as the intersection of both constraints is not empty.

In contrast this wouldn't work:

```
import java.util.*;
class Test {

   public static <E extends CharSequence, T extends E> doIt(List<E> in) {
     return null;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final List<CharSequence> in = new ArrayList<>();
      final List<? super Integer> out = doIt(in);
   }
}
```

Because there is no class that would comply with both bounds as `CharSequence` is not super of `Integer`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but could be that <? super String> and <? extends CharSequence> are not mutually exclusive bounds ?

Can you provide an example for your second paragraph ? It's not clear

Comment: @michael laudrup. What I mean with not mutually exclusive is that there are at least one class that complies with both constraints. In this case they are ```String``` and ```CharSequence``` themselves. In contrast, if you had ```<? super Integer>``` rather than ```<? super String>``` then there is no class that would meet both constraints... the compiler knows this because ```CharSequence``` is no super-class/interface of ```Integer```.