# Convert one object to another using generics

Tags: java, generics, pojo

I have two classes `Foo1` and `Foo2` very similar fields.
And I have a convert method that accepts `Foo1` class as shown below

```
public static <T> T convert(IFoo1 foo1, Class<T extends IFoo2> clz) {
    T foo2 = clz.newInstance();
    // Setter methods
    return foo2; 
}
```

But I'm getting error : Syntax error on token "extends", , expected

Both the classes `Foo1` and `Foo2` implements interface `IFoo1` and `IFoo2`.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: please paste your error ;)

Comment: Also, this seems like a poor use of generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is because your generic is using improper bounding.

Change your method declaration to:

```
public static <T extends IFoo2> T convert(IFoo1 foo1, Class<T> clz) {
    T foo2 = clz.newInstance();
    ....
    return foo2; 
}
```

There is another type of bounding you may have been thinking of. I recommend reading this SO question: [Understanding upper and lower bounds on ? in Java Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19795709/understanding-upper-and-lower-bounds-on-in-java-generics)