# Upper bounded generics VS superclass as method parameters?

Tags: java, generics

As far as I know, using an upper bounded generic and using a superclass as a method parameter both accept the same possible arguments. Which is preferred, and what's the difference between the two, if any?

Upper bounded generic as parameter:

```
public <T extends Foo> void doSomething(T foo) {}
```

Superclass as parameter:

```
public void doSomething(Foo foo) {}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an upper bounded type parameter. Lower bounds are created using `super`, which you can't really do for a type parameter. [You can't have a lower bounded type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4902723/1679863).

And that would make a difference, if you, for example want to pass a `List<T>`. So, for the below two methods:

```
public <T extends Foo> void doSomething(List<T> foos) {}
public void doSomething(List<Foo> foo) {}
```

And for the given class:

```
class Bar extends Foo { }
```

The following method invocation:

```
List<Bar> list = new ArrayList<Bar>();
doSomething(list);
```

is valid for 1st method, but not for 2nd method. 2nd method fails because a `List<Foo>` is not a super type of `List<Bar>`, although `Foo` is super type of `Bar`. However, 1st method passes, because there the type parameter `T` will be inferred as `Bar`.

Comment: I see. Is there any reason to use the superclass as the parameter though? Or is it just convention to use it when you can?

Comment: @Someone When you are just passing a single argument of type `Foo` or it's subtype, then you don't need a generic method. You can pass an instance of a subclass of `Foo` to a parameter type of `Foo`.

Comment: This answers a different question. In the original question, `Foo` is a supertype of `T`. Whereas in your case, `List<Foo>` is not a supertype of `List<T>`, so that's why it's different. In your case, a supertype for `List<T>` would instead be `List<? extends Foo>`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you only need a type variable when it's used in more than one place in class/method/field declarations. When you declare one on a method (rather than a class), the only places to use it are on the parameters and return value of that method.

For example, you can use it on multiple parameters to ensure their types match:

```
public static <T> void addToList(List<T> list, T element) {
    list.add(element);
}
```

This is a trivial example, but you can see that it prevents you from giving it an element that doesn't match the list's generic type:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
addToList(list, 7);
//addToList(list, 0.7); // doesn't compile
//addToList(list, "a"); // doesn't compile
```

You can also declare a parameter and the return type to be the same type:

```
public static <T> T nullCheck(T value, T defValue) {
    return value != null ? value : defValue;
}
```

Since this method is returning one of the two `T` objects it's given, we can safely say that the returned object is also of type `T`.

```
Integer iN = null;
Integer i = nullCheck(iN, 7);
System.out.println(i); // "7"

Double dN = null;
Double d = nullCheck(dN, 0.7);
System.out.println(d); // "0.7"

Number n = nullCheck(i, d); // T = superclass of Integer and Double
System.out.println(n); // "7"
```

As for the example in the question, the type variable is only being used once, so it's equivalent to using the superclass. In this case you should avoid declaring a type variable, it's just unnecessary clutter.

Also I should note that the other answer changes the example to use `List<T>` and `List<Foo>`, but as mentioned in the comments, the superclass is really `List<? extends Foo>`, so no type variable is needed there, either.