# When is ti appropriate to use declare generic argumens for the methods instead of simply usinf super class?

Tags: java, generics

I'm still thinking about such case - two method declarations:

```
public <T extends MyClass> void method1(T val)

public void method2(MyClass val)
```

what is the principal difference between these two declarations?
In either case I can use object of MyClass and it's child classes.

So what is the benefit of using generics here?

I will be thankful if someone explains this to me.
Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21390747/1787314 This should help you clear the doubt!

Comment: I posted an answer, but then [moved it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45573779/2643425) to the duplicate question, since the existing answer there is talking about a different situation and doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: In this case, there is no difference between the two and there is no benefit to the generic version.