# How to create a generic method whose parameter has to be a supertype of certain type only

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a generic method which takes a single parameter of supertype of single type by using super keyword.Is there any way to do so?

I want to do something like this, which is a s very basic requirement.Can somebody please provide me a roundabout since compiler doesnt allow me to define type using lowerbound(super)

```
public <T super LinkedHashSet> void check(T t){

    }
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? Looks like it should be `public void check(Set<?> set)`.

Comment: Object is a supertype of LinkedHashSet and any object is an Object. Not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I want that the parameter should be of type LinkedHashSet or it supertype

Comment: My question is **why**. It is not clear from your content, and by your intentions, you could pass `new Object()` as parameter and will compile fine.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes it should work fine.But It should also not allow me to pass a type of say String or Integer or subtype of LinkedHashmap.It can be only LinkedHashMap,HashMap,AbstractMap or Object

Comment: If i write this method in terms of Object,I can pass any class.But I want the method to accept a parameter of its own type or supertype

Comment: You may want to consider using an Interface (or even a marker interface).  Again, let us know what you are trying to do (not how you want to do it).

Comment: I want to have a method which takes a parameter and restrict its type to a super class of a particualr type.I hope I am clear

Comment: @ErstwhileIII Is there in way in generics we can do it by using super keyword like <T super Animal> ??

Comment: @AbhinavKumar *Why* do you want to do this? There may be other, cleaner approaches. Can you give us more specifics about the type of situation you would use this in, perhaps examples of how you intend to use `check`? Java doesn't really keep information about what types *inherit* from a given type. Also, you would be limited to only using methods of `Object`; so why not just operate on `Object`s?

Comment: @AbhinavKumar *It can be only LinkedHashMap,HashMap,AbstractMap* -- What about accepting `<T extends AbstractMap>` or `<T extends Map>` instead?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902723/why-cant-a-java-type-parameter-have-a-lower-bound