# Java generics super usage

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to understand why the following is not compiling.

```
public class AnimalHolder<T super Animal> {
        T animal;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                AnimalHolder<Object> objectHolder = new AnimalHolder<Object>();

        }
}
```

As I understand I can use anything that `IS` `A` `Animal` or super type of `Animal`(in this case `Object`). Can any one explain?

> Compiler Message:

```
AnimalHolder.java:15: error: > expected
public class AnimalHolder<T super Animal> {
                           ^
AnimalHolder.java:15: error: <identifier> expected
public class AnimalHolder<T super Animal> {
                                        ^
AnimalHolder.java:17: error: illegal start of expression
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        ^
AnimalHolder.java:17: error: illegal start of expression
        public static void main(String[] args) {
               ^
AnimalHolder.java:17: error: ';' expected
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                     ^
AnimalHolder.java:17: error: '.class' expected
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                                         ^
AnimalHolder.java:17: error: ';' expected
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                                             ^
AnimalHolder.java:21: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
8 errors
```

Comment: If you have a question about compilation failure, **always** post the compilation error message!

Comment: Possibly useful thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902723/why-cant-a-java-type-parameter-have-a-lower-bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you can't specify a *lower* bound for a generic parameter:

```
public class AnimalHolder<T super Animal> { // Can't do this
```

You can only specify an *upper* bound:

```
public class AnimalHolder<T extends Animal> { // Must use "extends"
```

Comment: To be honest, I didn't understand the difference between the two. That is why I posted this question.

Comment: `T super X` isn't very useful if you think about it. All you can say for sure is T is `Object`, which tells you nothing. Read the duplicate question for more info.