# How do I pass a generic parameter to a method?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to store objects that are a sub-class of an abstract class, but there is a problem illustrated here:

```
abstract class Letter {
    public void store_object(Letter letter) {
        HashMap<Class<? extends Letter>, ? extends Letter> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(letter.getClass(), letter); <-- this line throws an error
    }
}
class A extends Letter {}
class B extends Letter {}
```

The reason `map.put` throws an error is that `letter` is not a sub-class of `Letter` (it is a direct instance of `Letter`).

Is there a way to change the method parameter to be a generic sub-class of Letter? Something like:

```
public void store_object(? extends Letter letter) {
```

or

```
public void store_object(Object<? extends Letter> letter) {
```

The error is:

```
no suitable method found for put(Class<CAP#1>,NewClass19.Letter)
    method Map.put(Class<? extends NewClass19.Letter>,CAP#2) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; NewClass19.Letter cannot be converted to CAP#2)
    method AbstractMap.put(Class<? extends NewClass19.Letter>,CAP#2) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; NewClass19.Letter cannot be converted to CAP#2)
    method HashMap.put(Class<? extends NewClass19.Letter>,CAP#2) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; NewClass19.Letter cannot be converted to CAP#2)
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends NewClass19.Letter from capture of ? extends NewClass19.Letter
    CAP#2 extends NewClass19.Letter from capture of ? extends NewClass19.Letter
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error? And also, what do you mean by `it is a direct instance of Letter`? If `Letter` is abstract, how can you have a direct instance of it?

Comment: The error is posted. It relates to the fact that the `HashMap` is expecting a variable of type `? extends Letter` but instead it got a variable of type `Letter`. When I said "direct instance of `Letter`, this is what I was referring to.

Comment: Instead of using a `Map` you could use a `Set<Letter>` and if you need to know the type somewhere you could use `instanceof`. (This Set will also accept subclasses of Letter.)

Comment: I think you're adding complexity, not reducing it. YAGNI. I'm trying to figure out how to fix it now, though.

Comment: YAGNI definitely doesn't apply here because I have been needing and using this for years. It's only when I tried to combine the methods for `VFramePanel` and `VDialogPanel` into one supertype that I ran into issues. It's complex at first but once it's complete it reduces so many headaches regarding opening multiple windows, refreshing window content, etc..

Comment: If the solutions to your problems are too complex, there is a very good chance it is because you are not modeling your problem domain in a way to allow for simple solutions.  Elegant solutions begin with good design.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to do here, but this will make your code compile:

```
abstract class Letter {
    public <T extends Letter> void store_object(T letter) {
        HashMap<Class<? extends Letter>, T> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(letter.getClass(), letter); // <-- this line throws an error
    }
}
class A extends Letter {}
class B extends Letter {}
```

Why are you generating a new `HashMap` every time the `store_object` method is called? What is your real problem? Please read [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/200235)

Related: [Canonical Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

---

By the way, `Object<Anything>` is always wrong because `Object` is not parameterized.

---

So I saw your edit, and FYI this compiles for me:

```
private static HashMap<Class<? extends Test>, Test> map = new HashMap<>();

static void addTest(Test test) {
    map.put(test.getClass(), test);
}
```

What's your problem exactly?

Comment: The reason I ask about the XY problem is the real scenario is much more complex and difficult to duplicate. I'm illustrating the problem in a smaller form. It may be frustrating (thank you for the link) but when I ask problems that are close to my real problems, they go unanswered because of complexity.

Comment: @ryvantage Does my version (specifying the method type parameter `<T extends Letter> void ...`) help you solve your real problem?

Comment: Yeah, I know `Object<Anything>` is wrong, I was just using it to illustrate where my head was going. Sometimes that seems to help. *shrugs*

Answer (score 0):

Given `B extends A`, `Class<? extends B>` is *not* a subtype of `Class<? extends A>`, so using a generic bound of `Class<? extends Letter>` is useless.

Instead, specify the key type as simply `<Class<?>` and your code will compile (and you actually don't lose anything by doing this):.

Answer (score -3):

It needs to be `<? super  Letter>`  instead. There's a nice acronym to help you remember [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

If you want to use generic parameters do :

```
public <T extends Letter> void method(T arg1)
```

**^[oops there are no lower bounds (super) on type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902723/why-cant-a-java-type-parameter-have-a-lower-bound)

Edit: Just saw your edit. Originally I thought you were just placing objects into some collection. The static map declaration type arguments are correct. because this one instance will be used by everything for *both* usage and storage, so it needs to be `<Class<? extends>, VCorePanel>`.

```
static Map<Class<? extends VCorePanel>, VCorePanel> self...pm;
public static showPanel(T newInstance){
    ...
    VCorePanel OldInstance = self_panel_map.get(newInstance.getClass()); //use
    ...
    self_panel_map.put(newInstace.getClass(), newInstance); //storage
}
```

ps. if you are using java 8, you can just pass in a constructor as opposed to using the reflection library. look into it if you'd like.

Comment: Why are you suggesting `super`?

Comment: From the collection's point of view, it is 'consuming' those objects.  Consumption usually means you need super. (See link above). Example: you have a List<T>. You want to place Objects of class A into it. You can if A extends T. Meaning T super A.