# Why can't the Java compiler properly infer inheritance?

Tags: java, generics

Answer boils down to `Java does not support lower bounds on parameterized methods, because such a feature is "not useful enough"`, refer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902723/why-cant-a-java-type-parameter-have-a-lower-bound)

Given the following snippet:

```
package demo;

public class Demo {
    interface Foo { void foo(); }
    interface Bar { void bar(); }
    interface FooBar {
      <R extends Foo & Bar> R foobar();

      static FooBar create() { return new TypicalJavaFooBar(); }
    }

    private static final class TypicalJavaFooBar implements Foo, Bar, FooBar {
        public void bar() { System.out.println("foo"); }
        public void foo() { System.out.println("bar"); }

        public <R extends Foo & Bar> R foobar() {
            return (R) this;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FooBar x = FooBar.create();
        Foo foo = x.foobar();
        Bar bar = x.foobar();
        x.foobar().foo();
        x.foobar().bar();
    }
}
```

Without the explicit cast to `R` in `TypicalJavaFooBar#foobar` compiler fails with the following error

> Error:(13, 20) java: incompatible types: demo.Demo.TypicalJavaFooBar cannot be converted to R

My question is why? To me, it seems that the compiler should have enough info since `TypicalJavaFooBar` is clearly defined to implement both `Foo` and `Bar`; why isn't that enough to satisfy the `Foo & Bar` constraint?

**UPDATE**

The main goal of this exercise is to define the following contract: calling method `foobar` on an instance of a `FooBar` is guaranteed to return *something* that implements both `Foo` and `Bar`.

Comment: @horatius That has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: In `TypicalJavaFooBar` you can change the return type of the `foobar` method to just `TypicalJavaFooBar`, which also does away with the cast. While this does not answer your question, this is what I would probably do in this situation. Though I generally prefer composition above inheritance and thus am unlikely to encounter this situation. :-)

Comment: @Andrey, unfortunately your "main goal" is not actually possible in Java's type system.  You can return something that is guaranteed to implement a specific interface, but you can't express "something that implements both of these interfaces."

Comment: @Louis Wasserman, yep you're right, I just tried making "Foo & Bar" a lower bound, but apparently "<R super Foo & Bar>" isn't valid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't a Java type parameter have a lower bound?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902723/why-cant-a-java-type-parameter-have-a-lower-bound)

Answer (score 6):

The type parameter `R` is bound to the method *by the calling code* and could theoretically be `Baz implements Foo, Bar`; see, for example, `Collections.emptySet()`, whose type parameter is determined by the caller and can be influenced by a type witness.

To do what you are apparently attempting, you would need to move the type parameter onto the interface `FooBar` and have `TypicalJavaFooBar implements Foo, Bar, FooBar<TypicalJavaFooBar>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `R` can be any type which is a `Foo & Bar` so you can write

```
 class MyFooBar implements Foo, Bar { ...


 FooBar x = new TypicalJavaFooBar();
 MyFooBar mfb = x.foobar(); // this compiles now with the cast.
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the compiler cannot inference the type of R and your cast is wrong.
To see why, just extend your class like this:

```
static class C extends TypicalJavaFooBar {

    void eat() {}

    @Override
    public void bar() {}

    @Override
    public void foo() {}
}
```

Then, your cast allows this:

```
FooBar x = new TypicalJavaFooBar();
C c = x.foobar();
c.eat();
```

Which results in a RuntimeException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: demo.Demo$TypicalJavaFooBar cannot be cast to demo.Demo$C
```

That is why -- surely the designers of the compiler would not allow this. There is something wrong in the code, hence the **necessity** of the cast.

Comment: I updated the answer, i was just trying to keep the demo short... honestly, I find non-final, public classes or final classes with public constructors to be a horrendous practice ever since Java 8 came out. also, you're missing the point. the point here is to make the following contract explicit: calling method "foobar" on an instance of a "FooBar" is guaranteed to return *something* that implements both "Foo" and "Bar".

Comment: If you find non-final, public classes horrendous, you will not like other features of the language, like the necessity of cast to show the risk of ClassCastException at runtime.

Comment: static factory methods in interfaces = not dealing with public classes. also, what *would* make it work is defining Foo & Bar as a *lower* bound, i.e.: "<R super Foo & Bar>", i see no valid reason why specifying lower bounds is not supported...

Answer (score 0):

If you could use this in Java

```
if (obj instanceof (Foo & Bar))
```

then you would not be forced to make the cast.

Comment: The necessity of the cast is here to show the risk of java.lang.ClassCastException at runtime.

Comment: It could be..IDK...but to me there is no logical difference between `if (obj instanceof (Foo & Bar))` and `if ((obj instanceof Foo ) & (obj instanceof Bar))`, but the first does not compile however