# Java Generics why do we need wildcard (question mark)?

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to understand why do we need the wildcard -- question mark in Java Generics, why can't we just use the normal single character T or E etc. as the type? Look at the following example:

```
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    App a = new App();
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    strList.add("Hello");
    strList.add("World");
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    intList.add(1);
    intList.add(2);
    intList.add(3);

    a.firstPrint(strList);
    a.firstPrint(intList);

    a.secondPrint(strList);
    a.secondPrint(intList);
}

public <T extends Object> void firstPrint(List<T> theList) {
    System.out.println(theList.toString());
}

public void secondPrint(List<? extends Object> theList) {
    System.out.println(theList.toString());
}

}
```

The result is same albeit the wildcard version is more concise. Is that the only benefit?

Comment: The wildcard means "of any type". `extends Object` is redundant in both cases.

Comment: Thanks @user202729. So <T super String> doesn't work but <? super String> works. Why don't just make that "T" work the same way?

Comment: @shmosel I know. I just use that to test syntax. Of course everything is an Object.

Comment: That's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902723/why-cant-a-java-type-parameter-have-a-lower-bound).

Comment: And... comments are only for suggesting improvements, not for extended discussion or asking another question.

Comment: @user202729 Got it. Probably when we need something like this: default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)

Comment: One difference is that you could refer to `T` inside the code of `firstPrint`.

Answer (score 2):

The "?" is there to act as a placeholder where you are allowed to pass the different type of objects.

Normally, T and ? is used in generics as a placeholder. i.e `<?>` or `<T>`.

Use Cases:

`<?>:` It could be used while developer wants to allow any type of object for particular instance.

> Example: `List<?> listOfObject = new ArrayList<>();` Here in this case
>   listOfObject can accept any kind of object which is extending the
>   class **Object**

`<T>:` One of the approach to be used it complex type of Object (DTO).

> i.e., Let's say if Class A can have same fields for different instances.
>   However, there is one field which could be varied with the type of
>   instances. Meanwhile, it could be the better approach to use Generics with

Example:

```
public Class A<T> {

   private T genericInstance;

   private String commonFields;

   public T getGenericInstance() {
      return this.genericInstance;
   }

   public String getCommonFields() {
      return this.commonFields;
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      A<String> stringInstance = new A<>(); // In this case, 
      stringInstance.getGenericInstance();  // it will return a String instance as we used T as String.

      A<Custom> customObject = new A<>();   // In this case, 
      customObject.getGenericInstance();    // it will return a custom object instance as we used T as Custom class.
   }
}
```

Comment: They don't mean the same thing.

Comment: "only allows you to pass lists of type object" - what other types of list are there?